# jQuery custom functions with .data and html5 data atributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, append

I am trying to append a new "app" to my "AppList" when a button is clicked.

**JS**

```
$(".appCreate" ).click(newApp);

function newApp() {
    var facebookTemp = $("#facebook-template").html();

    var appName = $(this).data("appName");
    var appSize = $(this).data("appSize");
    var appTemp = $(this).data("appTemp");

    $("<div class=\"app" + appName + appSize + "\"></div>").html(appTemp).appendTo(".AppList");
};
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

    <section id="AppBox">
        <div class="AppList">

<!-- == Facebook == -->
            <div id="facebook-template">
                <div class="App facebook Size170x290">
                    <h1>Hello Test</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<!-- == Settings == -->
    <section id="dialog-settings" class="dialog" title="Settings">
        <button data-appName="facebook" data-appSize="Size170x290" data-appTemp="facebookTemp" class="appCreate">
        Facebook</button>
    </section>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#facebook-template {
    display: none;
}
.facebook {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #133783 0px, #102E6D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #133783;
}
.facebook { top:120px; left:0; }
#AppBox {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:0;
}
.AppList {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.App {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    margin:5px;
    padding:0;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 1px black;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    cursor:move;
}
.Size170x290 {height:170px;width:290px;}
```

Basically the thing isn't showing up and i don't know whats causing it.

Comment: I wish down votes required people to leave a comment. You've provided code.

Comment: Where is `.AppList` in your html?

Comment: Is there an element with class AppList in your HTML ? It seems not.

Comment: sorry i left that out for some reason :Z

Comment: @MarcelGwerder i have updated the question to include the rest of the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You lost the context of your click handler.

This was an obvious first mistake:

```
$(".appCreate" ).click(newApp);
```

Second mistake is data names. Change to:

```
var appName = $(this).data("appname");
```

Notice the case. Convert all names to lower case.

I also added handlebars.js because of the conversation in the comments.

New working code:

```
$(".appCreate" ).click(newApp);

function newApp() {
    var facebookTemp = $("#facebook-template").html();

    var appName = $(this).data("appname");
    var appSize = $(this).data("appsize");
    var appTemp = $(this).data("apptemp");

    var template = Handlebars.compile(facebookTemp);
    var html = template({
        app : appName,
        facebook : appTemp,
        size : appSize
    });

    $(".AppList").append(html);
};
```

Live [DEMO && CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/epyyP/1/).

Comment: the click function still works but this is a better way of doing it. this hasn't fixed my problem though. i will add more of the HTML code now

Comment: Edited the post to fix other problems. GL :)

Comment: Thank you very much :) one more thing before i confirm answer is i dont want the content to be facebookTemp. i was hoping that it would then lead to the other variable `var facebookTemp = $("#facebook-template").html();` and set that as the html...

Comment: Please correct me if this is not what you mean. Change .html(appTemp) to .html(facebookTemp). You should probably use a template engine like handelbars.js to replace template values. Or maybe you can get away with changing values with jQuery for now.

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/epyyP/1/ Notice I included Handlebars library.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! that's exactly what i was looking for. Something to create templates and call them on demand. i will have to read into Handlebars libary :)

Comment: yea i know i could change .html(appTemp) to .html(facebookTemp) but i wanted to have multiple apps :)

Comment: So you need to load different template for different app? You can have multiple templates and load appropriate depending on which button someone clicked. Just replace the selector $("#facebook-template") with something like $("#" + $(this).data("template")). Link should have a template id on data-template.

Comment: Np. Handlebars is very small. You will quickly master it.

Comment: ahh man i wish i read this earlier i just made a function for each individual app because i couldn't get it to work :Z oh well i guess i can clean everything up once i have the groundwork's sorted